# Can I load into an array all the CSS classes into an array listed in the styleUrls property of an Angular Component

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In my Angular component I wish to load one of the CSS files used in my app so I can collect the contained CSS classes, put them into an array and loop through them in my component's HTML template. I know from previous experience that in JavaScript/TypeScript I can load all of my CSS stylesheets into JavaScript/TypeScript like so:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.styleSheets, (styleSheetList: any) => {
      console.log(styleSheetList.cssRules); // do something
});
```

This is okay but a little inefficient and I shouldn't really call "document" in my Angular component file as I have heard this is considered an anti-pattern.  So could I add the specific CSS file to/through my component's `styleUrls` property then somehow expose it in my component and loop through the classes there?

Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'css-list',
  templateUrl: './css-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css-listcomponent.scss', 'the-file-i-want-to-iterate-through.css']
})
export class CssListComponent implements OnInit {

  // so let's load the style sheet
  ngOnInit() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.styleUrls[1].cssRules, (cssRules: any) => {
          console.log(cssRules); // do something
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You want all the classes into and array and display it to the user so user can select is this what you want

Comment: I want to list all the CSS classes contained in a specific file and load it into an array, I will then use this array to set classes in the HTML template using a ngFor